# Redux Socket IO Example action isn't being seen and/or returned (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, socket.io, redux

Terminal is only giving me initial console log for connection but not the console log for it's action. It was working the other day and not sure what's going on now. I'm using redux-socket.io from https://github.com/itaylor/redux-socket.io.

I'm hoping to get their example working so that I can integrate it into my app. Here's what the `server.js` looks like:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
var socket_io = require('socket.io');
server.listen(3000);
var io = socket_io();
io.attach(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log("Socket connected: " + socket.id);
  socket.on('action', (action) => {
    if(action.type === 'server/hello'){
      console.log('Got hello data!', action.data);
      socket.emit('action', {type:'message', data:'good day!'});
    }
  });
});
```

Then, within the terminal I'm running `node server.js` which gives me "Socket connected WmLHWgyVafV32bxIAAAv" several times with a different id each time.

On the client side, I'm doing everything within `store.js`. There's already quite a lot going on here so I'm wondering if there's a conflict in here as well that I'm not seeing or understanding so I'll paste the full code:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel2 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel2';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import logger from 'redux-logger';

import reducers from '../redux/reducers';

import createSocketIoMiddleware from 'redux-socket.io';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
const socketIoMiddleware = createSocketIoMiddleware(socket, "server/");



const middleware = [thunk];


const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel2,
  blacklist: ['network', 'floop_reducer', 'plops_reducer', 'ziggity_reducer', 'swooty_reducer'],
};


if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  middleware.push(logger);
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, reducers);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
  applyMiddleware(socketIoMiddleware),
);



//--------------EXAMPLE REDUCER--------------//
function reducer(state = {}, action){
  switch(action.type){
    case 'message':
      return Object.assign({}, {message:action.data});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
//--------------EXAMPLE ACTION--------------//
store.dispatch({type: 'server/hello', data:"Hello!"})

store.subscribe(() => {
  console.log('new client state', store.getState());
});



export const persistor = persistStore(store);

// https://blog.reactnativecoach.com/the-definitive-guide-to-redux-persist-84738167975
```

Whenever I run `react-native run-ios` I get my simulator up with a node React Packager running metro bundler on port 8081. I then run 'node server.js'.  The action does run through immediately on the client side, so I'm expecting to see "Got hello data! good day!" on the server side terminal. All I'm getting is the "Socket connected WmLHWgyVafV32bxIAAAv" as I mentioned before.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!!!